# Is the slugs table required when using the friendly_id gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id

In the friendly_id gem docs it says to create a table `slugs` where all slugs are created. But in addition it gives me the opportunity to add a column to my model table to increase performance using cached_slugs.

My question is: Is the `slug table` neccessary even though I use the `cached_slugs` column in my model table? Data would be redundant. I tried to delete my slugs table but then I got an error when creating a new entry in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use slugs with friendly_id you have to use slugs table . 
In friendly_id Many slugs could reference same resource , slugs are not permalink , but only a seo friendly name .
If you want something ligter than friendly_id i suggest to use stringex.

https://github.com/rsl/stringex

but , anyway , freindly_id work great and fast using cached_slug entry.

UPDATE:

The current version of `friendly_id` (4.0) does not require the `slug` table unless you're using the `slug history` option.

More info available here: http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/file/Guide.rdoc

Look under the `Example Setup` and `History` subheadings.

Comment: in another way you could use friendly_id without slug passing use_slug=false options ... but you lose almost any  advantage of friendly_id

Comment: Is there a way to make friendly_id use unique slug names? So it validates and doesn't allow multiples of the same name, no more --1 and --2??

Comment: the slug is generated from a column or instance method on the object. Including a `validates_uniqueness_of` on the column you're using for the friendly_id should do the trick.